# Why did GitHub CI just start failing to locate libcurl?

Tags: ubuntu, continuous-integration, libcurl, apt-get, github-ci

CI was working just fine but now it's failing. I don't believe anyone has made any changes to test environment or the set `.yml`. It just looks like `libcurl4-openssl-dev` is no longer available?!?

The line breaking CI in .github/workflows/tests.yml:

```
...
jobs:
  lint-and-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
...
steps:
  - name: Install libcurl  
    run: sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libcurl4-openssl-dev   <== this one
  - name: Install libvips
    run: sudo apt-get install -y libvips
...
```

And here's the error down around line 24:

```
 1 Run sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libcurl4-openssl-dev
 2  sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libcurl4-openssl-dev
 3  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
 4  env:
 5    RAILS_ENV: test
 6    POSTGRES_HOST: localhost
 7    POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres
 8    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
 9    GITHUB_TOKEN: ***
10   BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM: x-access-token:***
11   MANDRILL_API_KEY: ***
12   CUCUMBER_FORMAT: progress
13 Reading package lists...
14 Building dependency tree...
15 Reading state information...
16 Suggested packages:
17  libcurl4-doc libidn11-dev libkrb5-dev libldap2-dev librtmp-dev libssh2-1-dev
18 The following NEW packages will be installed:
19  libcurl4-openssl-dev
20 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
21 Need to get 322 kB of archives.
22 After this operation, 1543 kB of additional disk space will be used.
23 Ign:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libcurl4-openssl-dev amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13
24 Err:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libcurl4-openssl-dev amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13
25  404  Not Found [IP: 52.154.174.208 80]
26 E: Failed to fetch http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4-openssl-dev_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.13_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 52.154.174.208 80]
27 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
28 Error: Process completed with exit code 100.
```

`apt-get` can't find libcurl?!?

I'm more familiar with Homebrew (Mac) package installer. How can I point apt-get to the right source?  Or maybe there's a Ubuntu image on GitHub CI that already includes it?!?

Comment: It's probably a temporary glitch -- try again in a few hours. I'd add `--no-install-recommends` to your libvips line as well: the debian package will pull in 800mb of unnecessary stuff without it.

Comment: 3 days and still `404 Not Found`. Is there a more standard way to install this library?

Comment: Ah I see you're still using focal. I would update to 22.04, the current stable version.

Comment: Specifying `runs-on: ubuntu-latest` in **tests.yml**. Not sure how to get a more recent stable version.

Comment: I have `matrix:
        include:
          - name: "Linux x64 (Ubuntu 22.04) - GCC 11"
            os: ubuntu-22.04`
 fwiw